# dividing the title of d3.v4.js bar graphs in two or more lines

Tags: javascript, d3.js

[image]
I am using d3.v4 graphs they are working perfectly fine but the title of my bar graphs are too long, I want to divide the title in two lines.

```
svg.append("g")
.attr("class", "y axis")
.call(yAxis)
.append("text")
.attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
.attr("y", 6)
.attr("dy", ".71em")
.style("text-anchor", "end");    
var state = svg.selectAll(".state")
    .data(data)
    .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "g")
    .attr("transform", function (d) {
        return "translate(0," + y(d.State) + ")";
    })
```

`d.State` contains the title, this is what I have tried so far:

```
return "translate(0," + y(d.State.text().split("+")) + ")";
```

The '+' sign is in the title and I have inserted that to split the title in two half.

Comment: Can you add pls a screenshot?

Comment: That question makes little sense, the `transform` attribute expects a **number**. Why would the translate have anything to do with the size of the text?

Comment: @oma i have shared the screen shot, as u can see the titles are big i can't display them in one line.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado i am new at this would you please help me out in dividing my title in two or more lines based on a character like '+', it could be any character.

Comment: As I said, your problem is clear but your code is not. So, please take your time and create a running demo, using [blockbuilder](http://blockbuilder.org/), [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or any other site you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y2fI7.png)
this code worked for me

```
svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end");

  var state = svg.selectAll(".state")
      .data(data)
      .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "g")
      .attr("transform", function(d) {
         return "translate(0," + y(d.State) + ")"; 
       })

  $('.y .tick text')
  .each(function(d){
      var self = d3.select(this);
      var lines = self.text().split("+");
      self.text("");
      self.append("tspan")
        .attr("x", -8)
        .attr("dy", "0em")
        .attr('font-weight', 'bold')
        .text(lines[0]);
      self.append('tspan')
        .attr("x", -8)
        .attr("dy", ".92em")
        .style('fill', '2E3092')
        .text(lines[1]);
    })
```